# Flutter Safe Area issue

Tags: android, flutter, safearea

I am developing an app where I need to use the safe area to avoid unnecessary swiping. Though I have implemented the safe area in a custom container to render the screens, it leaves a white margin on top.

When I add these parameters to the `SafeArea()` widget,

```dart
top: false,
maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
```

the white space goes away. However, the size of the app bar is too big. This is the minimal code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class DashboardActivity extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardActivityState createState() => _DashboardActivityState();
}

class _DashboardActivityState extends State<DashboardActivity> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      //top: false,
      //maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          leading: InkWell(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          middle: Text(
            "Dashboard",
          ),
        ),
        body: Text(
          'This is an example use of SafeArea',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: example image]

This only happens on tall displays, i.e. something more than an 18:9 aspect ratio.

**Can someone tell me what's wrong and how can I fix this?**

Comment: Does this help? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Comment: Wrap the body with safa area instead of the scaffold.

Comment: SafeArea´s purpose is to prevent intrusions by the operating system and not to prevent swiping - I think you are mixing up different concepts here.

Answer (score 2):

`SafeArea` is basically the same Padding widget. The difference is it adds padding to its child widget when it is necessary (For example, it will indent the child by enough to avoid the status bar at the top of the screen).

The reason why it is working on smaller screens is that `SafeArea` doesn't add any padding there (it is like to have something like this `padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0)`)

When you are wrapping your `Scaffold` inside `SafeArea` on taller screens it is calculating necessary padding value and adding it to `Scaffold`.

This is why you are getting this:
[image]

The correct use case of SafeArea is to use it inside `body:`.

Flutter `AppBar` and `CupertinoAppBar` widgets is handling device screen types by themselves.